# Light fixture troubleshooting

Tags: wiring, light-fixture, multiway-switch

Light fixture in basement stopped working. Checked the bulb and wiring and looked good.

When I use the switch in a 3 way switch set up, the light fixture only works if the adjacent recessed ceiling lights are off.

For example, It works if I switch the fixture on alone, but switches off when I turn on the ceiling lights simultaneously. Or, if I turn on ceiling lights first, the fixture won’t respond at all when I use the switch.

Any advice on what would be going on?

Comment: Did anyone change any switches or add any fixtures? Is this a new problem?

Comment: I added this fixture over a year ago and it just now started acting up. 

Something I just noticed as I was playing around with it. The fixture switch works inversely with the dimmer of the ceiling lights. Ex: if the dimmer is low, the fixture light gets stronger and vice versa. The fixture switch doesn’t have a dimmer feature.

Comment: Pictures of all the wiring involved would be most helpful, as would a diagram showing how the switches are wired to the lights (path of the wiring).

Comment: I could take the switch apart, but literally nothing has changed from earlier when it worked and I haven’t modified this since then. And I don’t want to add to my problem lol

Took the fixture apart, checked the connections, wired to corresponding wires. Everything looks solid. 

Cannot think of a reason it would’ve changed so suddenly.